# Show preview when switching windows with ⌘+Tab

Tags: window-manager

The `⌘+Tab` key combination switches between active and background windows on my MacOS on MBP.

When hitting this combination, a small preview of the selected window appears. Another hit on the `Tab` key while `⌘` is pressed previews and selects the next window. Releasing the `⌘` switches to the currently selected window.

Recently, this preview does not appear, so I can't efficiently switch to other windows using a key combination.

Any idea how to restore that preview, please?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by rebooting. The preview appears correctly now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Restore Defaults

Further steps below:

Have you tried restarting your machine and doing your system updates?
Have you tried using the right and left command key with tab to try and make it work?